# Import Class on spark-shell where package name starting with word "spark"

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have opened Spark-Shell. In shell we already have an variable -

```
spark: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
```

I have a third party Jar which has package name starting with "spark",  like -

```
spark.myreads.one.KafkaProducerWrapper
```

When I try to import above package on spark shell then 'm getting exception -

```
scala> import spark.myreads.one.KafkaProducerWrapper
<console>:38: error: value myreads is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
       import spark.myreads.one.KafkaProducerWrapper
```

How can I import such a package on Spark-Shell resolving above conflict.

I'm using `Spark-2.0.0` , `JDK-1.8` and `Scala -2.11`

Comment: $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages spark.myreads.one.KafkaProducerWrapper

Answer (score 0):

Use _root_ as beginning part like this:

`import _root_.spark.myreads.one.KafkaProducerWrapper`